# Optimize nested for loop query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables **Emp** & **Emp_Details**

```
Emp -> EmpId, EmpName
Emp_Details -> EmpDetailId, Domain, Year, Date_of_record
```

Each employee has many domains, where their perfomance is measured, and it can be measured more than once a year.

So emp1 can have more than one recodes in Emp_Details for Domain1 for year 2015.

Now I want to fetch latest records per Domain per year for an employee.

Currently I'm fetching using two nested FOR loops in Java, i.e. one FOR loop for each factor and another inner FOR loop for each year fetching latest Date_of_record.

How should I optimize it?  I'm using PL/SQL.

Comment: can you at least post a snippet of your code?

Comment: @Vance sorry due to some proprietary issue, I'll not be able to post the code. Really sorry.

Comment: @jarlh, yes it has, updated my answer

Comment: @reiley Nobody wants to steal your code, especially as it is apparently not very optimal.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, haha, still cant do. I was just helping a friend, it was not mine. Thank you.

Comment: Show us the complete stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `MAX` to find that years latest date (for each group).

```
select e.EmpName, ed.Domain, ed.Year, MAX(ed.Date_of_record)
from Emp e
  left join Emp_Details ed ON e.EmpId = ed.EmpId
group by e.EmpName, ed.Domain, ed.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can also try Analytical function to suffice your requirement. Let me know if this helps

```
SELECT a.empid,
  a.empname,
  a.domain,
  a.dor
FROM
  (SELECT e.EMPID,
    e.EMPNAME,
    ed.DOMAIN,
    ed.Date_of_record dor,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ed.EMPID,ed.DOMAIN ORDER BY ed.Date_of_record DESC) rnk
  FROM emp e,
    emp_details ed
  WHERE ed.empid = e.empid
  )a
WHERE a.rnk = 1;
```